# A third column with values “dependant” on two or more other columns in an iGIS .glc-addon to shapefile?

Tags: sql, xml

I'm working with a protocol for aiding field data collection, the platform I'm using is the iOS version of GeometryITs iGIS app. 
I've created a .glc-file with lookup tables associated to a .shp-file to structure the way my colleagues are collecting their field data, it looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <GISLayerConfiguration>
<!-- A textual description of this configuration -->
<!--
    <description></description>
-->

<!--
    A CodeList is used to specify Name-Value-Pairs to be used in database tables.
    These Name-Value-Pairs are stored in 1 table, the lookup table, and then the
    codes are stored in other tables. Applications can then replace the code with
    the value to present to humans.

    The CodeList element must have name, type and length attributes.
    The name is used to create the lookup table.
    The type and length represent the code, not the value. This allows
    tables that are to be used with the CodeList to be validated.

    A value element represents 1 Name-Value-Pair.
    The code attribute is used to reference the value in other tables.
-->

<Attribute column="Tradart" readable-name="Trädart">

<Value data-type="N" length="10">
  <field-type>CodeList</field-type>
  <field-param>Tradart</field-param>
  <default>1</default>
  <prompt></prompt>
</Value>

<Visibility>
  <list>true</list>
  <edit>true</edit>
</Visibility>
</Attribute>

<CodeList name="" type="" length="">
    <value code=""></value>
</CodeList>
<CodeList name="Tradart" type="N" length="3">
    <value code="1">Alm</value>
    <value code="2">Ask</value>
    <value code="3">Bok</value>
    <value code="4">Ek</value>
    <value code="5">Gran</value>
    <value code="6">Hägg</value>
    <value code="7">Lönn, parklind</value>
    <value code="8">Oxel</value>
    <value code="9">Rönn</value>
    <value code="10">Sälg</value>
    <value code="11">Tall</value>
    <value code="12">Triviallöv</value>
</CodeList>

  <Attribute column="Diam_cm_in" readable-name="Diameter i centimeter - intervall">

    <Value data-type="N" length="10">
        <field-type>CodeList</field-type>
        <field-param>Diam_cm_in</field-param>
        <default>1</default>
        <prompt></prompt>
    </Value>

    <Visibility>
        <list>true</list>
        <edit>true</edit>
    </Visibility>
</Attribute>

<CodeList name="" type="" length="">
    <value code=""></value>
</CodeList>

<CodeList name="Diam_cm_in" type="N" length="3">
    <value code="1">0-30 cm</value>
    <value code="2">31-40 cm</value>
    <value code="3">41-50 cm</value>
    <value code="4">51-60 cm</value>
    <value code="5">61-70 cm</value>
    <value code="6">71-80 cm</value>
    <value code="7">81-90 cm</value>
    <value code="8">91-100 cm</value>
    <value code="9">Över 101 cm</value>
</CodeList>
    </GISLayerConfiguration>
```

Depending on the values entered in  and  I want to assign a value to a third column.
The command could look something like this:

`IF  <Attribute column="Tradart" value="1"> AND <Attribute column="Diam_cm_in"="7","8","9"> THEN <Attribute column="Results" value = "1">`

Any ideas on how to make this work? I'm a bit embarrassed to admit I don't even know what language in using, and therefore not which syntax to use...

This post is actually a re-post from earlier today, when I posted on http://gis.stackexchange.com
I realized this is probably a topic more related to actual XML or SQL programming than the general GIS topic.